# Как записать во внешнюю переменную значение полученное в Observable в RxJava2?

Tags: java, kotlin, rxjava, rxjava2

Не могу записать в переменную `typesOfResponsibility` значение `it`, полученное из `Observable.fromCallable` при подписке `subscribe`

```
fun getById(id: Int) : TypesOfResponsibility {
            var typesOfResponsibility : TypesOfResponsibility? = null
            Observable.fromCallable{
                typesOfResponsibilityDao.getById(id)
            }
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe{
                    typesOfResponsibility = it
                }
            return typesOfResponsibility
        }
```

Comment: Вы делаете что-то странное. Обычно такой метод возвращает `Observable` или нужный тип, но без использования rx. `subscribe` точно внутри делать не надо. Чтобы советовать правильный вариант нужно больше информации, однако 99% вам надо переписывать логику так, чтобы метод возвращал именно `Observable`. Причём проще всего это сделать на уровне `Dao`

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб есть задача вызвать из внешнего кода на view.js интерфейс, возвращающий данные из БД, как это сделать?

Comment: Задача мне не знакома, но, думаю, вам надо из вашего метода на Kotlin вернуть просто выборку из БД, а уже на `JS` обернуть этот запрос в `rx`, для избежания блокирования главного потока.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обернуть метод из Kotlin в rxJs во View-коде? Это поможет предотвращению блокировки главного потока?

Comment: Теоретически. Ничего не знаю про связь js с кодом на Котлин и вообще о вашей ситуации. Я думал, вы про андроид, а у вас неизвестно что. Наверное сайт на Kotlin Native? Добавьте деталей в вопрос, а то ничего не понятно

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Короче в Android-проекте решили сделать UI часть на View.js, (не знаю для чего это сделали, но это факт) во view.js опрокидываются  функции получения данных из kotlin таким образом:
val web = WebView(this)
web.addJavascriptInterface(stateRepository, "\$dbResponsibility")
web.loadUrl("http://localhost:$PORT")
Из view, как я понял будет вызываться этот метод: stateRepository.getById(id)

Comment: Ого, какое извращение) Возникает вопрос - а зачем тут вообще `rx`? Без него что-то не работает или работает не так? Кажется, при описанном вами способе `rx` вообще прикрутить никак нельзя.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб согласен, извращение еще то... Причиной для UI на View стал недостаток опыта в Android-разработке, но по мне как это в разы усложнило весь проект.. Rx хотел прикрутить для реализации паттерна наблюдатель, то есть, как только получили данные, возвратить их поребителю

Comment: Боюсь, ничего тут посоветовать не могу. Разве что, что опробованный вами способ точно работать не будет - rx работает не так. Можно, конечно, rx-ом получить данные и из метода их вернуть, но это просто лишит смысла использование rx-а... Будь я на вашем месте - выкинул бы код с `WebView` и переписал бы с нуля. Но тут много деталей, наверное, вам согласовывать надо...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо за ответ, самое интересное то, что на WebView написали то по херне..) Но меня не слушают, я тип джун и ничего не понимаю)

Comment: Нельзя получить результат асинхронной операции сразу после ее вызова. В Котлине с этим помогут coroutines и suspended functions. Но использовать их вместе с RX, как маслом масло намазывать.